# Down-sample raster map with average algorithm

Tags: gdal

I need to down-sample a map to new map with less resolution NOT for overview BUT to new map file with smaller size

I need to do that with gdal Utils

Answer (score 4):

you can use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) for that, with the -tr parameter to set the output pixel size.
For example, with input cell size of 10 m resampled to 50 m (so 25 times smaller in number of pixels)

```
gdalwarp -tr 50 50  -r average raw_image.tif resampled_image.tif
```

note that you can also use [gdal_translate,](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) but then with less control on the resampling method but the advantage of being able to use more option on the output image (such as compression)

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -outsize 20% 20% raw_image.tif resampled_image.tif
```

**UPDATE**: with the release of gdal v 2.0, additionnal resampling method became available with gdal_translate. You can thus also use the **-r average** option

> -r {nearest (default),bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}:
>       (GDAL >= 2.0) Select a resampling algorithm.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: how can I control the average window?

Comment: it will be the average of the pixel with their center in the new pixel.

Comment: Creation options can be specified with both [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) and [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).  SO either way you can specify compression settings.

Comment: you have the same creation options, but not the same resampling options